# Play custom sound in Xamarion IOS local notification

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I am trying to play custom mp3 sound file of (10-25 seconds) with local notification. I have placed the custom sound file in iOS project folder (same level as Resources) with BundleResource as BuildAction. I have also placed the sound file in Resources folder with same build action. It seems both doesn't work.

```
var content = new UNMutableNotificationContent
            {
                Title = title,
                //Subtitle = "Notification Subtitle",
                Body = body,
                Badge = 1,
                Sound = UNNotificationSound.GetSound("music.mp3"), //play custom sound
                UserInfo = NSDictionary.FromObjectAndKey(NSObject.FromObject(id), NSObject.FromObject(notificationKey))
            };

            var trigger = UNTimeIntervalNotificationTrigger.CreateTrigger(10, false);
            var requestID = "request_" + id;
            var request = UNNotificationRequest.FromIdentifier(requestID, content, trigger);
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.AddNotificationRequest(request, (err) =>
            {
                if (err != null)
                {
                    throw new Exception($"Failed to schedule notification: {err}");
                }
            });
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works fine, my phone sound was mute.